# React : How to use the result of an API call, in my JSX? (scope problem)

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm trying to use the result of my API call (response) to display it in my JSX at src level.

But because of the scope, I don't have access to "response". I tried declaring response as an empty variable in global scope before assigning it in my useEffect, but it doesn't work.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const toFetchProfilPicture = async () => {
      try {       
        const response = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:4200/api/user/image/${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user_id}`
          );
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    };
    toFetchProfilPicture();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <form className="modal__infos" onSubmit={saveChange}>
        <div className="modal__photo"> 
          <img src={response.data[0]} alt="profile_picture" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I could not use a function to have "response" in the global scope, but I would like to do otherwise.

How do I use "response" in my JSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a state variable containing a string (the image URL):

```
const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    const toFetchProfilPicture = async () => {
      try {       
        const { data } = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:4200/api/user/image/${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user_id}`
          );

          setImgSrc(data[0])
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    };
    toFetchProfilPicture();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <form className="modal__infos" onSubmit={saveChange}>
        <div className="modal__photo"> 
          <img src={imgSrc} alt="profile_picture" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: OMG it was so obviously... thanks a lot, it works !